# is there any way to refactoring or improve this code?

Tags: java, refactoring

Have the next code,

Main:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GroupOfUsers group = new GroupOfUsers();
        List<String> users = group.getUsers();
        System.out.println("The users are: " + users);

    }
```

Class GroupOfUsers:

```
public class GroupOfUsers {
    
    private static HashMap<String, Integer> usersWithPoints = new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{
        put("User1", 800);
        put("User2", 550);
        put("User3", 20);
        put("User4", 300);
    }};

    public List<String> getUsers() {
        List<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Sorting users by points
        usersWithPoints.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())
        .forEachOrdered(x -> users.add(x.getKey()));

        //Capitalizing the names of the users
        List<String> usersCapitalized = new ArrayList<String>();
        users.forEach(x -> usersCapitalized.add(x.toUpperCase()));

        return usersCapitalized;
    }
}
```

**Question:**

What things would you refactoring from this code? would u improve anything?, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not try to avoid creating objects. You're dealing with a user, therefore create a User object. The code will be much easier to read and maintain. Let me show you:

```java
public class User {

  private String name;
  private int points;

  public User(String name, int points) {
    this.name = name;
    this.points = points;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  public int getPoints() {
    return this.points;
  }
}
```

```java
List<User> usersWithPoints = Arrays.asList(
  new User("User1", 800),
  new User("User2", 550),
  new User("User3",  20),
  new User("User4", 300)
 );

return usersWithPoints
  .stream()
  .sort(Comparator.comparingInt(User::getPoints).reversed())
  .map(User::getName)
  .map(String::toUpperCase)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```